# Bokeh server on one computer, serving another computer

Tags: python, server, bokeh

Probably a simple question. I'm a newbie

I have a local computer (computer 'A') and a remote computer (computer 'B').

I want to run a bokeh server on B and have the results show up in A's browser when I browse to localhost:8000.

First I created this file on B. It just has a simple plot with a slider. You slide the slider and the plot changes. It works when I run it on A.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server

def modify_doc(doc):

    # Initialize the data
    power = 1
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = x**power

    # Initialize the plot and slider
    p = figure()
    p_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
    p.line('x', 'y', source=p_source)
    s = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="multiplier")

    # When the slider is changed, redraw the plot
    def callback(attr, old, new):
        x = p_source.data['x']
        y = x**s.value
        p_source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)
    s.on_change('value', callback)

    doc.add_root(column([p, s]))


def main(_):
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))
    server_kwargs = {}
    server_kwargs['port'] = 8000
    server = Server({'/': bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop, **server_kwargs)

    server.start()

    io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    io_loop.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

So I copy this file to B and I run it on B by ssh'ing in and typing:

```
python barebones.py
```

Then on A I type:

```
ssh root@123.123.123.123 -N -D 7000
```

Note I typed 7000 not 8000. I've tried both; I don't understand why some things I've read online tell me to use a different number there.

Next I open Firefox > Preferences > Network proxy > Settings > Manual proxy configuration. I set SOCKS host to 'localhost' (without quotes) and port to 7000 and choose SOCKSv5. Click OK. In Firefox's address bar, browse to http://localhost:8000. (Note I said 8000 there not 7000. Again, not sure if that is correct but I've tried various permutations.) It says "Unable to connect".

I tried inserting this in the script but it didn't seem to have any effect. Maybe I'm way off here:

```
from bokeh.server.util import create_hosts_whitelist
allow_websocket_origin = ['0.0.0.0:8000']
port=8000
create_hosts_whitelist(allow_websocket_origin, port)
```

I know there is another way to run a bokeh server using "bokeh serve ..." command at command line, but I'm trying to create a standalone script if possible.

Gah. This should probably be simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

On `B`, run:

```
bokeh serve filename.py --address 0.0.0.0
```

You can then access the application from another computer with the URL `http://Bs_name_or_ip_address:5006/`. If there is a firewall running on the `B` computer, you have to allow incoming traffic on the port.

To override the default port number (5006), use the `--port NNNN` argument.

See also:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html

Answer (score 2):

following command worked for bokeh 1+ versions

```
bokeh serve --show filename.py --allow-websocket-origin=*:5006
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is really old but I run into a similar problem and managed to solve it using the suggestion posted here: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/CmweAdzkWXw

Maybe this helps someone else:

On the node where Bokeh will run:

```
bokeh serve &
ssh -NfR 5006:localhost:5006 user@gateway
```

On the local machine (e.g., laptop):

```
ssh -NfL localhost:5006:localhost:5006 user@gateway
```

Now you should be able to navigate to http://localhost:5006 to access Bokeh running on a node behind the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, sometimes bokeh says

Refusing websocket connection from Origin http: //< bokeh_server_ip_address>:8000;                       use
--allow-websocket-origin=: 8000 or set BOKEH_ALLOW_WS_ORIGIN=:8000 to permit this; currently we allow origins {'localhost:8000'}

```
bokeh serve --show file_name --address 0.0.0.0 --port=8000 --allow-websocket-origin=<bokeh_server_ip_address>:8000
```

bokeh_server_ip_address is the remote server ip where you want to host the bokeh application